# How to spoof an IP for application that needs this particular IP?

Tags: iptables, firewall, port-forwarding, redirection, spoofing

In general, such a problem, there is a system RHEL 6.4 Server with a pair of network interfaces combined into one by bonding. This system IP address: `10.7.7.1`. Next on the system running an application that needs to connect to the MySQL-server `10.7.7.2` on port 3306 . And in fact, MySQL runs on `10.7.7.3`. Connection settings in the application are hardcoded therefore can not be changed . That can be heard through **iptables** do address translation . How to make so that when the application attempted to `10.7.7.2:3306` **iptables** is intercepted and sent a request to `10.7.7.3:3306`, and got a response back, and feed it to the application?

Comment: Is anything using the 10.7.7.2 address? Can you add an additional IP to the MySQL machine?

Comment: This is not possible, I just need to redirect.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with NAT rules in iptables.

If the MySQL server is on the same host, use a REDIRECT rules.  Redirect all connections to port 3306 not to 10.7.7.3 to the required address.

If the MySQL server is not on the same host the, use a DNAT rule.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that

- .1, .2, and .3 are different machines
- You can't swap .2 & .3's IP Addresses
- .2 is running Linux

Here's what you need to add on .2:

```
-t nat -A PREROUTING  -d 10.7.7.2 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.7.7.3
-t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 10.7.7.3 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j SNAT --to-source      10.7.7.2
```

HOWEVER...

If for some reasons you can't create iptables rules on .2 and/or you want to intercept the traffic on .1, all you need to do on .1 is:

```
-t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 10.7.7.2 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.7.7.3
```